# How do I break up the controllers (views) into cohesive files in a Django project?

Tags: python, django

I am currently working through the tutorial on Django's website. Upon completing the following command:

python manage.py startapp polls

it creates the following structure:

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

As I was going through the tutorial it occurred to me that the views file could grow to this huge incohesive monolithic file that has every action in the entire web application.

Is there a way to break this file up into cohesive classes or files? I tried changing the settings.py and the url.py to point to a different directory, but it appears that the script that generates the file structure creates a "views" module when it creates the file, and I don't see a way to change/override this behavior from the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each app you create for the project will have its own `views.py` file (assuming it uses views), so you don't need to worry about it becoming monolithic.

Just make sure to keep your apps' functionality focused.

From the Django docs:

> Projects vs. apps
>
> What's the difference between a
>   project and an app? An app is a Web
>   application that does something --
>   e.g., a weblog system, a database of
>   public records or a simple poll app. A
>   project is a collection of
>   configuration and apps for a
>   particular Web site. A project can
>   contain multiple apps. An app can be
>   in multiple projects.

Comment: Apparently running that startapp command is the same directory created  another "app", and I just needed to add that to the settings.py. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could split up views in a similar manner to how this blog entry splits models

http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/11/splitting-up-django-models/

eg

```
/myapp

    * /views
          o __init__.py
          o bar.py
          o foo.py
```

with appropriate import statements in the __init__.py file

This might be appropriate for an expanding app. Also views are more flexible than models in the way they can be structured so you could do backend/ members/ frontend/ modules or just admin_views.py etc.

Comment: That's a good idea if you want to expand your views across many files instead of one big file.  Rails, Pylons and others seem to follow that structure.

Comment: the good thing about django app structure is it's not unneccessarily complicated to start off with and you can pretty much do whatever you want as long as you reference it in the urlpatterns. 

However the novice might have trouble managing complexity with growth if they arent given a nudge in that direction. so theres pluses and minuses

Answer (score 1):

The view functions don't have to be in `views.py`, they can be anywhere, as long as they're mapped properly in `urls.py`. So it's up to you how you organize your project.

> but it appears that the script that generates the file structure creates a "views" module when it creates the file, and I don't see a way to change/override this behavior from the script.

You can totally ignore that script and what it generates. It doesn't do anything magical behind the scenes; it just creates those files for you.

Answer (score 0):

I worked though that tutorial recently. I had figured that most of the "core" logic would go in to various classes or methods in other supporting files. Then the views.py would contain basic calls to setup and execute the methods.

Given this design, I'd expect that a single view function might end up with 3 to 5 lines of code. Setup, execute method and return.

Basically, what I mean is an implementation of the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

I expect the tutorial avoided this approach because it adds levels of redirection (misdirection?) that can make it harder for a introductee to follow the code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I do to make my apps' views more compact is to factor my views pretty aggressively.  I hate writing any code twice, so this comes naturally for me.  Anywhere I can, I use a generic view to perform the needed actions.  A good percentage of the functionality of my views is decorators, which perform common actions on the views that need it.

for instance, I have a post_limit decorator that checks if the user has recently modified any instance in a certain model(configurable view by view) and produces an error if she has, as a means of flood protection.

In fact, many views work so similarly, that they don't even get their own function bodies, I just wrap generic views with the appropriate decorators, and the only views that get much custom code are aggregation type sites, such as the landing page, that collect lots of different information in subtle ways, so that they look 'just right'